# Ensuring C++ Array Parameter Size at Compile Time

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, compile-time

Is there anyway to ensure the length of an array parameter at compile time in C++? Such that:

```
void foo(T arr[3]);

int main()
{
    T a[5] = { /* ... */ };
    foo(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Would produce a compile time error?

Is the only way to ensure this using a template type such that

```
template <int N, class T>
struct Array{
   T arr[N];
};

void foo(Array<3, T> &arr);

int main()
{
   Array<5, T> a;
   foo(a);
   return 0;
}
```

Or is there a more idiomatic way of handling this?

Comment: Don't create it. It's already been done for you: `std::array`/`boost::array`. That is the proper solution, though.

Comment: I just found that after doing some deeper Googling. I can't seem to find a solution for multidimensional arrays. Would a C++11 style typedef be the right way around:


`template<class T, int N, int M>
using array2d = array<array<T, M>, N>`

Answer (score 2):

You can define the function to take a reference if you really want the compile time error:

```
void foo(T (&arr)[3]);
```

Comment: This seems to be the most parsimonious solution over using the STL and templates. Thank you. I assume this works for multidimensional arrays as well: `void foo(T (&arr)[3][5]`?

Comment: Oh, of course it does! The second dimension has to be ensured at compile time even without a reference to an array. Should've thought harder about that one.